# update_post_meta not saving when value is zero

Tags: post-meta

I have a problem with the `update_post_meta` function.
I have a user submitted value, which I pass via `$_POST` and then saving to post meta.

All is working fine, but when the value is `'0'` the post meta is not updated.

My code:

```
$id = absint($_POST['ex_id']);
$key = (string) $_POST['id'];
$value = (string) $_POST['value'];

echo update_post_meta($id, 'wpptabs_' . $key, $value);
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "until the value is not '0' _(other digits work fine)_"? Isn't that a contradiction? Which value are you referring to? You also might want to show your code in more context.

Comment: I have corrected the sentence to be more clear. However I do not have more code. There is a form which passes values via $_POST. And here is the whole code that fetches it on the other side.

Comment: Of course there is more code. These lines don't exist in a vacuum. What file are they in? Is this a plugin? Functions.php? A theme? What triggers this code? Is $value actually passing 0, or is it an unchecked checkbox - in which case it may not be passing anything at all.

Comment: `0` will resolve to `false` under some circumstances. That may be part of the problem, but as @vancoder has requested, we need more code.

Answer (score 3):

`update_post_meta()` calls `update_metadata` which begins with this line:

```
if ( !$meta_type || !$meta_key )
    return false;
```

I wrote a simple test (with a lot of cut & paste) to see how string values of 0 are evaluated (instead of looking it up in the PHP manual):

```
<?php

$meta_key = (string) 0;

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "0 exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "0 remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = (string) 0;

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "(string) 0 exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "(string) 0 remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = (string) '0';

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "(string) '0' exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "(string) '0' remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = 0x0;

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "0x0 exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "0x0 remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = (string) 0x0;

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "(string) 0x0 exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "(string) 0x0 remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = '0x0';

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "'0x0' exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "'0x0' remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';
$meta_key = (string) '0x0';

if ( ! $meta_key )
    echo "(string) '0x0' exits function<br />";

else {
    echo "(string) '0x0' remains in function<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;\$meta_key = $meta_key<br />";
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;(integer) \$meta_key = " . (integer) $meta_key . '<br />';
}
```

The result was:

```
0 exits function

(string) 0 exits function

(string) '0' exits function

0x0 exits function

(string) 0x0 exits function

'0x0' remains in function
  $meta_key = 0x0
  (integer) $meta_key = 0

(string) '0x0' remains in function
  $meta_key = 0x0
  (integer) $meta_key = 0
```

So, to add a value of 0 you could change it to the string '0x0' and cast it to integer when retrieving it. 0x0 is binary (I think) for 0.

Comment: `0` is one of the values considered `false` when you evaluate it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

PHP treats `0` as equivalent to `false` for comparisons. Because the `update_post_meta` function checks for a value before saving, it's exiting because `0 == false`.

You could do something like this before saving the post meta, it's a bit hacky but it would work:

```
if ( 0 === $value ) {
    $value = 'zero';
}
```

Then when you're retrieving your values later, you just do the opposite:

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta-key', true );
if ( 'zero' == $value ) {
    $value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to do with this part of `update_metadata()` function within `meta.php` that `update_post_meta()` calls

```
$result = $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where );
if ( ! $result )
    return false;
```

As the return value is `0` then the if statement correctly treats it as false, albeit `0` has been saved to the database.

This only happens when it updates. If a new post meta is added with a value of `0` then it returns the line id as expected.