# Saving zero in meta box

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox

So I have created a meta box for a review rating. Sometimes the value of the rating (out of 5) is zero.

When you enter a 0 into the input and save the data, it doesn't process because of the fact 0 also means false in the statement:

```
if ($meta_value) ...
```

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to save the zero value?

The only answer I have found is to enter 0x0 and then convert it (as per: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96536/17411), but for users it seems like a confusing task to explain, and then for them to remember..

---

This is my save_meta:

```
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $meta_review_fields_1;

// Verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
    return $post_id;  

// Check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;

// Check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
        return $post_id;
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
}


// Loop and save: Review
foreach ($meta_review_fields_1 as $field_1) {
    $old_1 = get_post_meta($post_id, $field_1['id'], true);
    $new_1 = $_POST[$field_1['id']];
    if ($new_1 && $new_1 != $old_1) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field_1['id'], $new_1);
    } elseif ('' == $new_1 && $old_1) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field_1['id'], $old_1);
    }
}
```

Mind you, I need it to delete the content of other fields if empty, just the rating input that should allow the value of 0.

Comment: How can 0 be a rating, surely 0 is the equivalent to nothing, ie. no rating, no? If someone said rate a movie from 1 - 10, it wouldn't make any sense if they said 0, would it? Just curious on your reasoning for considering 0 a valid rating.

Comment: Sorry, its an average rating. So there are 5 criteria for the rating. If they really fail an aspect then they get a 0. It is not uncommon to get zeroes.

Comment: Ah hah, i knew i was missing something, naturally there are cases where a zero does make sense. :)

Comment: An alternative would be a dropdown or radio buttons.

Comment: Would a `elseif ('' == $new_1 && $old_1 || 0 === &new_1) {` work? Or would it cause errors later on?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue seems to be with too loose logic check, rather than saving.

To treat valid but *falsy* value correctly you need something like this:

```
if ( false !== $meta_value )
```

This will strictly match only the case when value doesn't contain `false` (return of the API when fetch failed).

Comment: At which line would this go? `if ($new_1 && $new_1 != $old_1) {`?